# how to show my app as a destination in Photos in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cfbundledocumenttypes

I am developing a app. I Want to show my app in photos sharing option, I just heard that it is possible now. I added the type in document types but app still not showing. Any help where is the problem.
[image: Document Types]

**----------**

**some one had closed this question wrongly. Now this is possible in iOS 8, Using Share extension Technique**

Comment: this question is not duplicate of any other question, i had searched it a lot on this form and non of question is answering my problem. Will please add link if you think it is copy of other question

Comment: in iOS 8 it is possible they say but why it is not showing my app? I am testing it on beta ios8

Comment: I added the link to your question. Probably the same code will work with iOS 8 not with beta. Check this also https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1587/_index.html

Comment: thanks, but as you see in screen shot i am following that same link. but it does not show my app in photo sharing option

Comment: does we need to add some thing else to show my app in sharing option in ios8

Comment: The "duplicate" question is pre-iOS8, this question appears to be iOS 8 specific. Vote to reopen since the OS level support has changed.